# using credentials originally created from PHP library

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-api-php-client

We are using the PHP version of the client library to create authorization credentials, which we then store in a database.  I would like to write a script that uses those same credentials with python.  I tried using client.Credentials.new_from_json(), but then realized what we store isn't everything required by that method.

So I'm looking for advice on if I should be storing the data differently initially (when retrieved from PHP), or if I should be able to create a Credentials object in another method, using only the authorization token we currently store.

For clarity's sake, here is what we currently store:

{"access_token":"**string here**","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"**string here**","refresh_token":"**string here**"}

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT:

I hacked this to work with the following code.  I think it's pretty apparent this isn't a good solution, but just wanted to make sure I was on the right track and in theory everything would work, once I got a well formed Credentials object by one way or another.

```
secrets = [the contents of client_secrets.json]
creds = '{"access_token":"string here","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"string here","refresh_token":"string here"}'
creds_dict = json.loads(creds)
creds_dict['_module'] = "oauth2client.client"
creds_dict['_class'] = "OAuth2Credentials"
creds_dict['client_id'] = secrets['installed']['client_id']
creds_dict['client_secret'] = secrets['installed']['client_secret']

#this is a date a la "2013-09-23T06:13:04Z" in a real to_json formed Credentials object
creds_dict['token_expiry'] = 'none' 
creds_dict['token_uri'] = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
creds_dict['user_agent'] = None
creds_dict['invalid'] = False
creds_final = json.dumps(creds_dict)
return creds_final
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not construct an instance of [OAuth2Credentials](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials-class.html) using the data you have.